# Jenkins Groovy loop over json

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to loop over json and build a jenkins job according to how many instance_names in the json. check my code, I have put two print line to see what's the output I get and I get only instance names but no image family key.

this is the output of println

```
> webserver
> [Pipeline] echo
> webserver
> [Pipeline] echo
> api
> [Pipeline] echo
> api
```

```
        stage("Create Instances"){
            steps {
                script {

                    def instances = [ 
                        [ instance_name : { 'websever' }, image_family : { 'ubuntu' } ], 
                        [ instance_name : { 'api' }, image_family : { 'redhat' } ]     
                    ]

                    def list = ['instances': instances.collect { [instanceName: it.instance_name(), imageFamily: it.image_family()] } ]

                    def ig = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(list))
                    def parser = new JsonSlurperClassic()
                    def json = parser.parseText(ig)


                    for(int i = 0; i <json.instances.size(); i++){
                        println json.instances.instanceName[i]
                        println json.instances.imageFamily[i]


                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

imageFamily is not printing here too, I want to trigger build job two time since I have two servers in the json and pass imageFamily parameters accordingly to the job. Please help

Comment: If I run your code in console, it prints `websever ubuntu` and then `api redhat`. Also why do you need that strange conversion java-json-java?

Comment: and why do you have values in closures - `instance_name : { 'websever' }` when it could be just `instance_name : 'websever'`

Comment: i bet changing accessor should fix your problem: `json.instances[i].imageFamily`